# Pull Request Metrics in Stash

Tags: git, pull-request, bitbucket-server

We've been asked to generate metrics around how many code reviews we have been doing.  Is there a way in Stash/Git to extract historic pull requests performed on the repo?  In particular, the following would be useful:

- Date/Time of the request
- Requestor Name
- Approver Name
- Date/Time of the approval

Comment: [Stash has an API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.0.1/stash-rest.html#idp963664) which you might be able to use for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already suggested by [Robbie Averill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294327/pull-request-metrics-in-stash#comment54388285_33294327), you can use the [Stash REST APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/reference/rest-api.html) for this, more specifically the [Stash Core REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/latest/stash-rest.html), which *provides REST resources for core Stash functionality such as server administration, projects, repositories, pull requests and user management*:

`GET` [/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/latest/stash-rest.html#idp36368) yields the [paged](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/latest/stash-rest.html#paging-params) list of open pull requests against the repo in question. The response contains most of the information you are looking for already, notably the pull request dates, the `author`, `reviewers` and even `participants`:

```json
{
    "size": 1,
    "limit": 25,
    "isLastPage": true,
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "version": 1,
            "title": "Talking Nerdy",
            "description": "It’s a kludge, but put the tuple from the database in the cache.",
            "state": "OPEN",
            "open": true,
            "closed": false,
            "createdDate": 1359075920,
            "updatedDate": 1359085920,
            "fromRef": {
                "id": "refs/heads/feature-ABC-123",
                "repository": {
                    "slug": "my-repo",
                    "name": null,
                    "project": {
                        "key": "PRJ"
                    }
                }
            },
            "toRef": {
                "id": "refs/heads/master",
                "repository": {
                    "slug": "my-repo",
                    "name": null,
                    "project": {
                        "key": "PRJ"
                    }
                }
            },
            "locked": false,
            "author": {
                "user": {
                    "name": "tom",
                    "emailAddress": "tom@example.com",
                    "id": 115026,
                    "displayName": "Tom",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "tom",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "AUTHOR",
                "approved": true
            },
            "reviewers": [
                {
                    "user": {
                        "name": "jcitizen",
                        "emailAddress": "jane@example.com",
                        "id": 101,
                        "displayName": "Jane Citizen",
                        "active": true,
                        "slug": "jcitizen",
                        "type": "NORMAL"
                    },
                    "role": "REVIEWER",
                    "approved": true
                }
            ],
            "participants": [
                {
                    "user": {
                        "name": "dick",
                        "emailAddress": "dick@example.com",
                        "id": 3083181,
                        "displayName": "Dick",
                        "active": true,
                        "slug": "dick",
                        "type": "NORMAL"
                    },
                    "role": "PARTICIPANT",
                    "approved": false
                },
                {
                    "user": {
                        "name": "harry",
                        "emailAddress": "harry@example.com",
                        "id": 99049120,
                        "displayName": "Harry",
                        "active": true,
                        "slug": "harry",
                        "type": "NORMAL"
                    },
                    "role": "PARTICIPANT",
                    "approved": true
                }
            ],
            "link": {
                "url": "http://link/to/pullrequest",
                "rel": "self"
            },
            "links": {
                "self": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://link/to/pullrequest"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "start": 0
}
```

### Approval Dates

What is missing still is the exact date of approval, though you can approximate it from the pull request `closed` date if you happen to use [Checks for merging pull requests](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stash/checks-for-merging-pull-requests-323389150.html#notfound) and require at least one approval.

- Ideally a `GET` on [/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests/{pullRequestId}/activities](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/latest/stash-rest.html#idp157520) should return these details per reviewer, but unfortunately the `fromType` is only documented to support either COMMENT or ACTIVITY, but not APPROVAL.
- If you desire this functionality, I suggest to watch(vote/comment on the related issue [Indicate which pull request approvals are "out of date" (BSERV-3887)](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-3887) (or open a more precise new one of course).

Comment: what is the date format the api is printing ? for example: 1359075920

Comment: @ravi - this is [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is _defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970_. This is one of the two frequently used time formats in APIs, with the other (and considerably more human friendly) being [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).